# Quotient group confusion: G/Ker(f)

Tags: group-theory

From the First Isomorphism Theorem:  Let $f:G \to K$ be a surjective homomorphism. Then $K \cong G/Ker(f)$.

I'm confused upon the meaning of $G/Ker(f)$. I know the notation means left cosets, but I can't seem to understand the meaning behind $G/Ker(f)$.

Comment: $Ker(f)= H$ is a subgroup of $G$, where $H = \{ g \in G, f(g) = 1_K\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Think of $G/ker(f)$ as a way of clumping together all the elements that ruin the chance of your map being a bijection into one single coset (which is the identity element in our factor group), namely $ker(f)$.

Edit for clarification:

The remaining cosets/elements of our factor group are determined by how the kernel of the map partitions the group.

A nice and easy to visualize example would be the map $\phi : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(x,y,z) \mapsto z$. The kernel of this map is all points $(x,y,0)$, and so cosets of $\mathbb{R}^3/ker(\phi)$ look like $(0,0,z) +\{(x,y,0): x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$. You can imagine this factor group as dividing $\mathbb{R}^3$ into planes whose values under the map are determined by their height $z$.

So if we have a surjective group homomorphism we can always create an isomorphism with the factor group $G/ker(f)$ (which is a group since the kernel of a homomorphism is always a normal subgroup).

Hopefully this helps, and let me know if there is anything you would like further clarification on.

Comment: Could you clarify more on what you mean by the remaining left over cosets? I 'm kind of confused on that detail.

Comment: Edited the post for you.

Comment: So are you saying that Ker(f) is being deleted from all of your cosets?

Comment: No it is not being deleted, every element that gets sent to $0$ (or the identity element of the other group more generally) is being all put into a SINGLE coset. In the example above, this coset is when $z=0$.

Comment: Is it possible that you could provide a general visual for this concept? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Actually I just remembered that in Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra they have a section on quotient groups which gives a visualization which might help you.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to see the idea, so (0,0,z) is the identity element in the example provided above and that identity + the element in R^3 creates another element (or another coset). Is my thinking correct?

Comment: $(0,0,0)+\{(x,y,0)\}$ is the identity element of the factor group.

Answer (score 0):

$\ker f$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so $G/\ker f$ is a quotient group.

A concrete example: Consider $f:\mathbb{Z}\to2\mathbb{Z}$, $f(x)=2x$.

Then $f$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $0$, so this means $\mathbb{Z}/0\cong\mathbb{Z}\cong 2\mathbb{Z}$.